# Error when uploading Raster files that previously worked

Tags: r

I have a set of .tif files that I am trying to import using the Raster package. Previously it was working fine. I have ensured that the .tif files are all in the folder on my hard drive that I am trying to pull them from using the following code:

```
rm(list=ls())
unlink(".RData")
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(PopGenReport)

mydsn<-"~/RasterFiles"
setwd(mydsn)
CRS("+init=epsg:4267")
ColNrthResist<-raster(paste0(mydsn,"colnrthresist01.tif"))
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

Error in .local(.Object, ...) :

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  :
Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)

```
##check wd is set properly 
 getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/mhugh/Documents/RasterFiles"
```

I have also tried using the readr::read_file(file_name) and get a similar error. I was running this code last week with no issues and am unsure where the error is coming from. I know this has been asked a couple times but none of the answers posted are working for me.

Edit: I have also tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling R with no solution (still getting the same error)

Comment: you should be okay with  `mydsn <- './'`, given where your working directory is set.

Comment: unfortunately that still gives me the same error.

Comment: what does `list.files( full.names = TRUE)` give you?